# How do I access the actual secrets from AWS Secrets in .NET core? Syncfusion

Tags: .net, .net-core, syncfusion, aws-secrets-manager, ej2-syncfusion

I have tried multiple tutorials online and none have gotten me to where I can actually use a secret in my .NET build.

I am currently trying to just use the Amazon generated code but I it is still unclear to me how to get the secrets. I have close to 0 experience with .NET but it is necessary for 1 small part of my project and this is the only piece missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**csproj file**

```js
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.3.104.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.EJ2.AspNet.Core" Version="17.4.0.40" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.SecretsManager" Version="3.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Controller/AmazonS3ProviderController.cs file**

```js
using Syncfusion.EJ2.FileManager.AmazonS3FileProvider;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Syncfusion.EJ2.FileManager.Base;
using Amazon;

using System.IO;
using Amazon.SecretsManager;
using Amazon.SecretsManager.Model;

namespace EJ2AmazonS3ASPCoreFileProvider.Controllers
{

    

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [EnableCors("AllowAllOrigins")]
    public class AmazonS3ProviderController : Controller
    {



public static void GetSecret()
{
    string secretName = "TEST";
    string region = "us-east-2";
    string secret = "";

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    IAmazonSecretsManager client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region));

    GetSecretValueRequest request = new GetSecretValueRequest();
    request.SecretId = secretName;
    request.VersionStage = "AWSCURRENT"; // VersionStage defaults to AWSCURRENT if unspecified.

    GetSecretValueResponse response = null;

    // In this sample we only handle the specific exceptions for the 'GetSecretValue' API.
    // See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
    // We rethrow the exception by default.

    try
    {
        response = client.GetSecretValueAsync(request).Result;
    }
    catch (DecryptionFailureException e)
    {
        // Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
        // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
        throw;
    }
    catch (InternalServiceErrorException e)
    {
        // An error occurred on the server side.
        // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
        throw;
    }
    catch (InvalidParameterException e)
    {
        // You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
        // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion
        throw;
    }
    catch (InvalidRequestException e)
    {
        // You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
        // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
        throw;
    }
    catch (ResourceNotFoundException e)
    {
        // We can't find the resource that you asked for.
        // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
        throw;
    }
    catch (System.AggregateException ae)
    {
        // More than one of the above exceptions were triggered.
        // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
        throw;
    }

    // Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
    // Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
    if (response.SecretString != null)
    {
        secret = response.SecretString;
    }
    else
    {
        memoryStream = response.SecretBinary;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
        string decodedBinarySecret = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(reader.ReadToEnd()));
    }

    // Your code goes here.
}

        public AmazonS3FileProvider operation;
        public string basePath;
        protected RegionEndpoint bucketRegion;
        public AmazonS3ProviderController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            this.basePath = hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
            this.operation = new AmazonS3FileProvider();
            this.operation.RegisterAmazonS3("bucket-1", "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", "us-east-1");
        }
       
        // gets the image(s) from the given path
        [Route("AmazonS3GetImage")]
        public IActionResult AmazonS3GetImage(FileManagerDirectoryContent args)
        {
            return operation.GetImage(args.Path, args.Id, false, null, args.Data);
        }

    }
  
}
```

In the controller you will see where I need the access key and secret access key.

Comment: Hi @user68288 Did you able to fix this to get Secret keys from AWS in .Net Core ? Can you please share, I am also got stuck

Comment: Unfortunately I never figured it out, the tool we were using proved to not do what we needed it to. (syncfusion)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your ‘AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID‘ and ‘AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY’ directly into your required place. For accessing the Access Key, please refer this [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-appendix-sign-up.html). Also, we can refer configuration file in which we can add the secret keys from your application. Please refer the below UGs for your further references.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/credentials.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/latest/developer-guide/creds-assign.html

For further details for this, refer AWS UG.